# subscript in legend of R plot

Tags: r

I want to write x subscript 0 in legend but I am unable to do this

```
legend("topright",c(paste("pinnacle / mean = ", m, ",x[0]= change point / mean = 0.5"), paste("pinnacle / mean = ", m, ", x[0]=change point / mean = 1"),paste("pinnacle / mean = ", m, ", x[0]=change point / mean = 2"),paste("pinnacle / mean = ", m, ", x[0]=change point / mean = 3")), lty=(1:4))
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to ask questions with minimal details.

Comment: no.. it's not working

Comment: @RuhulKhan Edit your post to reflect Bertlomiej's suggestion